# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10000

Tags: sql, iis, f#, windows-firewall

So I've been getting this error when I run my program, an F# web app, on my laptop, but not when I run it on my desktop. I know it has something to do with the firewall ports, and I've opened the port my web app uses, but for some reason I still get this error.

The web app is a simple Owin api with SPA front end, and it's meant to get data from my SQL Express database.

When it runs, my web app, is hosted on iis express and I've set it too port :1337. I've done a `netstat -a` to see all the ports, 1337 is set as listening, while :10000 isn't listed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is this tagged with f#, iis and sql? Please limit your tags to what's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address 127.0.0.1 is always a loopback port and is the same as "localhost". So you can't access that IP across a switch, a router, etc.

Find out the actual IP address of your desktop (where I presume your application is) and try to access it that way. For windows, you can do run "ipconfig" at the command prompt. For Linux you can run "ifconfig"

Comment: It's not that. I'm trying to access my laptops SQL Express.

Comment: If you're trying access only a local port on your laptop from an application on your laptop then the firewall doesn't even come in to play.

In your example above you said 127.0.1.1 instead of 127.0.0.1, perhaps that's your error. I just assumed it was a typo.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, it's 127.0.0.1:10000.

Comment: I assume you're on Windows. Try "netstat -a" at a command prompt and see if port 10000 is even listening and if so, by what?

Comment: port 10000 isn't listed. The port I've set in my project is though, 1337, it's set as listening.

Comment: Then you have to try to connect using 127.0.0.1:1337 not port 10000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148700/discussion-between-jackson-sentzke-and-difster).

Comment: Found the issue. F# compiles everything at runtime, and I had a couple of variables that are meant to connect to an Azure emulator, but I didn't have the emulator set up correctly. So when the emulator error'd the compiler took it as an sql error.

Comment: Interesting... But I'm glad you figured it out.